# IIS server logs using Fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I'm trying to implement a logging solution using Fluentd but there is no available plugin to get IIS server logs. Is there any solution to get IIS server logs using Fluentd?

Comment: // , Could you show some of what you have tried already, please, or link to research you've already done?

Comment: The alternative solution is to get events from filebeat and use fluentd to collect events using elastic beats plugin and then send the logs to elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the configuration of our log aggregator

```
<filter iis_log.raw>
  @type parser
  key_name message_raw
  reserve_data true
  remove_key_name_field true
  <parse>
    @type regexp
    expression /(?<time>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} [\d:]+) (?<message>.+)/
    time_format %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
  </parse>
</filter>

<filter iis_log.raw>
  @type parser
  key_name message
  remove_key_name_field true
  reserve_data true
  reserve_time true
  <parse>
    @type csv
    delimiter ' '
    keys srv_ip,req_method,req_uri,cs-uri-query,s_port,cs-username,c_ip,req_ua,req_referer,http_code,sc-substatus,sc-win32-status,time-taken
    null_value_pattern -
    null_empty_string true
  </parse>
</filter>
```

Comment: what is the reason to add 2 filter sections here??